# Website performance: linear gradients applied in PS or with CSS

Tags: css, performance, linear-gradients

What is better in terms of website performance, applying linear gradients to an image in PhotoShop (or another software) or doing it with CSS? I have found an answer from about 6 years ago and it said that images are faster, but I just wanted to check again now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Css. They may need more cpu performance but the gradient via css is scalable so you can use it for different display sizes.

Images are using bandwidth to load so your load time is higher if you want a nice gradient and it's a high resolution image.